# Why "res.add(new ArrayList<>(list));" here?

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        if(root == null) return res;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        helper(res, list, root, sum);
        return res;
    }
    public void helper(List<List<Integer>> res, List<Integer> list, TreeNode root, int sum){
        list.add(root.val);
        if(root.left == null && root.right == null){
            if(root.val == sum)
                res.add(new ArrayList<>(list));
        }
        if(root.left != null)
            helper(res, list, root.left, sum-root.val);
        if(root.right != null)
            helper(res, list, root.right, sum-root.val);
        list.remove(list.size()-1);
    }
}
```

I am working on [Leetcode 113. Path Sum II](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum-ii/). It's not about the problem itself. I want to know why I have to write `res.add(new ArrayList<>(list));` instead of writing `res.add(list);` directly in line 13.

Answer (score 6):

Writing `new ArrayList<>(list)` creates a new list, containing all the elements in `list`. This is required, since at the end of the function you are calling `list.remove(list.size()-1);`, you are thus modifying the `list` variable.

If you were to add `list` directly in `res`, the `remove` call would also modify `res`.

Another relevant example:

```
class MyClass {
    public int modify = 5;
}

class Test {
    public static void myFunction() {
        MyClass object = new MyClass();
        System.out.println(object.modify); // prints 5.

        ArrayList<MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add(object);

        object.modify = 800;
        for(MyClass item : myList) {
            System.out.println(item.modify); // prints 800.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`new ArrayList<>(list)` will make a copy of `list`, which will make sure the elements be stored into `res`.

Otherwise, after `list.remove(list.size()-1)`, the elements in `res` will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, when we add an object to the collection, it gets added to the main collection as a reference.But later if we make the changes in the object then those changes are reflected to the main collection also.

Here in this case, we need to remove the last element of the 'list' for backtracking it leads to removing the element in the 'res' arraylist also. So we have to create a deep copy of the 'list' as ' res.add(new ArrayList<>(list))' to maintain changes.